# how to make sub-topics in Kafka

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to represent **Topics** and **Sub-topics** in **Kafka**.
Example : Topic 'Sports' Sub-topic 'Football', 'Handball'

And as I know Kafka doesn't support this. what I am using now are Topics like this **'Sports_Football'** , **'Sports_Handball'**...
this is not really functional because when we need to when we want the Topic 'Sports' with all the subs we need to query all the topics for it.

we are also using **Redis** and **Apache Storm**. So please is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. There is no such thing as a "subtopic" in Kafka, however, consuming all topics that begin with the word 'Sports' is trivial. Assuming you're using Java, once you have initialized a consumer use the method `consumer.subscribe(Pattern.compile("^Sports_.+"))` to subscribe to your "subtopics." Calling `consumer.poll(timeout)` will now read from all topics beginning with 'Sports_'.

The only downside to doing it this way is that the consumer will have to resubscribe when new 'Sports_' topics are added.

Answer (score 5):

Apache Kafka doesn't support it, you are right. But Kafka supports message partitioning. Kafka provides garantee, that all messages with the same key go to the same partition.

You can consume all partitions, or only single one. So you basically can set different keys for the each sport in order to separate messages.

Comment: This is for the most part true, but each partition could contain multiple keys, so there's no way to guarantee that consuming from a single partition would only return one particular type of key without changing the partition assignment strategy. Of course it could be done, but it's not really what the spirit of a partition is.

Comment: @kellanburket yes, sure. You are totally right. In this case you just have to process a smaller amount of data.

Comment: Partition, are meant to distribute the process. and it is automatically assigned.
is changing the assignment strategy a safe idea?

Comment: @MaherBenTalebAli like leshkin says, it depends on size of each 'subtopic' relative to the others, but I would personally recommend against it. Not only would you compromise performance of bigger 'subtopics,' but changing the strategy would also require you to carefully manage the number of topic partitions, increasing the number when you add a new 'subtopic' (you'd also have to update the strategy in code), which could quickly become a nightmare. If partitions are empty, consumers assigned to those partitions will remain idle.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of using Redis streams,
using kafka-redis-connector you can push data to Redis streams.
but consider the benefits and inconvenients of Redis streams.

An other interesting solution is using Kafka Streams, so you can create subtopics.
Broker(Sport) ==> Sport_Stream(Football, Handball) ==> Consumer can receive topics from the Broker or receive a subtopic from the Stream.